# Unit of measure and Quantity in Purchase Orders

Tags: usability, user-behavior

I have written an application that my clients use to keep inventory. The inventory system includes a purchase order module. Each purchase order has a list of line items including:

- Description of item
- Quantity to order
- Unit of measure
- Unit price

among others. When asked about the "unit of measure" field, my response is always to use a unit label that reflects the manner in which you consume or resell the items. Here are a couple examples of what I mean:

- "cc" for liquid medication stored in a bottle
- "Bar" for a candy bar
- "Bag" for a bag of dog food

This is clear when the unit of measure being consumed or resold matches the unit of measure on a received invoice. My problem is when it does not match. For example, medication is usually sold by the bottle, but dispensed by the cc or pill, candy bars are purchased by the box or case and sold individually, and dog food can be purchased by the pallet and sold by the bag.

In my experience in the past few months, I have realized that's it's unrealistic for a user to translate boxes into bars or bottles into cc, but I have not yet found a good way to remove the need for the mental translation.

Should I set up a table for equivalencies (1 box = 12 candy bars, 1 bottle = 1000cc, etc) and ask the user which they are ordering? This seems like it would add a lot of complexity behind the scenes when a vendor changes their packaging or offers new options. I'd like to keep the whole process as easy as possible.

Am I thinking about this incorrectly? Is there a simpler more elegant solution?

Update:
Here are some line items I'm getting that don't work:

```
Cephalexin        1     Bottle     $100.00
Snickers         10     Box         $12.97
Dog food          1     Pallet     $122.50
```

These are almost completely useless to me because the units and quantities aren't useful when updating the inventory. People don't resell dog food by the pallet or antibiotics by the bottle.  This is what I need:

```
Cephalexin      100     Pill         $1.00
Snickers        120     Bar         $1.297
Dog food         20     Bag         $6.125
```

Those units, quantities, and prices directly correlate to the units that are consumed or resold. The first set are what the OEM vendor expects.

Comment: I have this exact same issue, in almost the exact same situation (medicinal units).

Comment: Here's [something I found](http://bit.ly/AcHmHg) (although it doesn't specify any algorithms for actually solving the problem).

Comment: @jberger is there a specific page you're referring to?

Comment: My initial idea was to store the quantity as a predetermined unit (e.g. mL).  The GUI allows a user to enter in a number and a label (e.g. [100] [cases]). "cases" is a multiplier which contains a scalar value to get to the actual amount of the stored value for that particular medicine.  The problem with this is how to store it (client or DB).  DB design is new to me.

Comment: page 47 (searched for "measure")

Comment: Expanding on previous post: Labels should include multipliers.  "cases" would seem a bad label.  A better one would seem "case of 12 @100mL" or "dose of 20mL".

Comment: How does your system maintain SKUs?

Comment: @dnbrv it doesn't. There no direct link to the vendors so products are identified by their description. This is all that is required to place an order with the vendors being used.

Comment: So is the DB key the only unique identifier used in the system? (SKU is the internal reference number not to be confused with UPC, which is universal.)

Comment: The description and vendor combined are also unique.

Comment: After reading the [SKU wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock-keeping_unit) I see where dnbrv is coming from.  This seems similar to the templates/multipliers that Aaron and I were discussing.  Except, an SKU would merely be the Id for a template/multiplier.  For instance, if the incoming unit was [box of 12 large Snickers], that would be an "SKU", and each box would translate to [12] [large Snickers], where [large Snickers] is the outgoing unit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding you have an application which thinks of products in terms of:

1. Inventory (and)
2. Products

The owner buys a box of chocolate bars, enters the new acquisition into the system.

The system need to be able to know how many bars (units) the new inventory contains in order to update the (customer facing) stock levels.

I don't think you can get away from the fact that the owner will need to provide information about the number of units their new inventory purchase without access to manufacturer supplied line data.

However, even so, I don't think the problem is insurmountable .. maybe you're over-thinking the problem?

---

This is the way I'd approach the problem:

- When entering information about a new inventory purchase, the owner needs to provide the number of generic units that each new acquisition of inventory contains.
- These (customer facing) units can either be fixed  / or variable (weight / volume)

**FIXED UNIT (can be sold individually)**

- The total number of units contained in the new inventory acquisition needs to be entered.
- It doesn't matter *what* these fixed units are - the owner can enter a text string representing them on entry of the inventory (eg. bar, pill, necklace, brush).
- A simple parser can be developed to deal with singular/plural versions of the string.
- This label can be used on the customer facing form.

**VARIABLE UNIT (sold by measured amount)**

- If the inventory is to be sold as variable units, the owner needs to decide whether they'll be sold using weight or volume.
- The total weight / volume needs to be defined.
- The granularity of measurement unit needs to be defined.
- The cost per variable measurement unit needs to be defined.

Hope this helps.

---

**Re. The unit problem mentioned below**

If the site owner is having a problem understanding to concept of a saleable unit, maybe the answer is to add the unit input fields into part of a natural language sentence, and to use the answer to provide an example of how the unit label would be used.

**VARIABLE UNIT**

The customer can purchase this product by the [_variable_unit_selectbox_input_].

Ajax feedback -> "Example: Joe Bloggs bought 5 [_variable_unit_selectbox_input_] of [_product_type_]"

**FIXED UNIT**

The customer can purchase this product by the [_unit_label_text_input_].

Ajax feedback -> "Example: Joe Bloggs bought 5 [_variable_unit_input_]s of [_product_type_]"

Comment: I think this is an excellent answer. My one hang up is how to explain this in a coherent way to somebody that has never been exposed to a system like this. My most common question is "what do I put for units here?" which I can't personally answer, but only provide a guideline. Even after explaining how it works, I still have people that do the complete opposite because they're not use to thinking in that way and get confused. If you can add a solution to that in your answer I will happily accept it.

Comment: I would provide some explanatory text asking your site owner to think about what the customer will be purchasing (unit) - and provide a few examples that are relevant to your customer's retail domain.

Comment: This is exactly what I've done, to no avail. Despite on-screen instructions and explanations, they still do it backwards on occasion. I'm beginning to think some fault lies with my explanations and I should be more verbose.

Comment: @Spara: Why the users don't understand: I'm a programmer and I have to read through the answer again to understand it. Now, think of first-time users who didn't design the system and who don't know it inside-out...  I'd stick with a mix of templates/multipliers that Aaron and I have been discussing.

Comment: @codeinthehole: I'm not understanding your usage of "fixed" and "variable" units.  The question has to deal with the differences between ingoing and outgoing quantities and how to handle different units.  Also, I don't understand your example in relation to the question.  Please include a template of the feedback as well as an example (the example is mixed).

Answer (score 1):

You should be selling in the unit that your customers expect, and then interpret that appropriately. Or in the unit you sell in - do you really sell BOTH boxes of bars and individual ones? If so, you might want to consider having them as separate products or variants.

When your customer has ordered 2 bar boxes, you indicate that 2 boxes of 12 each = 24 bars. Or if they order 2 bars - a separate item - you indicate 2 bars.

So start from the point that your customer expects to see, and clarify exactly what this means, where appropriate.

Comment: That part I'm clear on. What I'm having trouble is when my client orders the items to resell. The units my clients uses to purchase don't match the units used to resell so I need to reconcile that in the inventory when items are received.

Comment: @Sparafusile Back to my answer, you state to label the unit of measurement as you would consumer or resell, not purchase. I'm confused as it sounds like they are violating this principle.

Comment: They just can't wrap their head around the concept. They enter 1 box because that's what they want to buy, but don't realize it has to be in a until that will be resold.

Comment: I think you need to start by clarifying with the customers what they understand, and what they want to do. Let them do that, and then organise and inform around that.

Comment: @Sparafusile: yes, the inventory guy only does enter "1 box", because that's all he deals with.  However, the multiplier to the base unit is needed; hence, "1 [box of 12]" or "1 [box of 48]".  This would not be a hard concept to grasp for the inventory guy.

Comment: That's the problem. There is no "inventory guy". The inventory is handled by the business owner who is an expert in some other field, or the office staff who are usually not an expert in anything. In my opinion, having them create a translation table doesn't solve the problem of not understanding the different units and adds another layer of complexity in which mistakes can be made.

Comment: @Sparafusile: If they don't understand the different units, you could merely say, "When you type in "20", the computer doesn't know if you mean "20 liters" or "20 mL"."

Comment: Yes, that's one hurdle to get over, but they need to choose a useful unit too.

Comment: In that case, one would choose the smallest possible quantity dealt with for that product (e.g. Candy bars -> 1 bar, Liquid medicine -> 1 mL).

Comment: But that may not relate to what the customer expects. If they are bulk-ordering liquids, they don't expect to order 1mL - they are more likely to expect 1L. And they will not necessarily notice. WHat do you do when they order 1mL of something you only stock on 10L bottles? And do you have to price everything in mL - that could be fun.

Comment: A user-friendly input method is used to scale the units (see comments #4, #6 under the Question).  Note that I, myself, am still working through this problem.  Please don't withhold a solution if you know of any.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the problem is with the inventory system rather than the software since you did if based on your clients' requirements. The standard of warehouse management is to assign SKUs (stock-keeping units) to every variation of an item carried, which includes colors, packaging, and storage sizes. Your software is suffering because there's no way to connect 1 candy bar sold in retail to the pallet of cases of boxes of candy bars that the warehouse receives from the supplier.

What you should do is go back to the drawing board with your clients and design SKU systems that work for them. SKUs are custom, occasionally long and descriptive internal identifiers. They should be tied to UPCs (universal product codes) to allow fast look-up in the warehouse & at the check-out. The complexity & detail level of an SKU system is entirely up to the inventory managers. Some people prefer them long and descriptive and others like them short.

In the database, one retail SKU can belong to multiple display, storage, and ordering units so that whenever the bulk container size changes inventory managers can easily order the right quantities.

For example, candy bars are sold individually and assigned a retail SKU of 12345. It is placed on the store shelf in a box that contains 36 of them, so the display unit (box) SKU is 12345-D36. In the warehouse, the boxes are stored in cases of 12, so the storage unit (case) is assigned SKU 12345-D36-S12. The cases are shipped & ordered in pallets of 50, so the ordering SKU will be 12345-D36-S12-O50.

For another example, let's consider a TV that is sold, displayed, and store individually but is shipped & ordered in pallets of 10. The base SKU in my system will be 54321 but since it's the same unit across multiple stages it'll be 54321-RDS1 and the pallet's SKU will be 54321-RDS1-O10.

Comment: This is a good answer, you obviously know what you're talking about. Unfortunately, it just wont work with my clients who are mostly very small business owners (1-5 employees) and who don't really want to put the effort into creating SKUs for every item. Inventory control is not the goal of my clients and they could never hire a full time inventory manager. I think, in my specific case, your solution requires too much overhead.

Comment: If they don't have the resources to implement a full-blown SKU system, you can at least implement container/packaging nesting in the software to make their lives easier. Your current system of unique identifiers is far from optimal even in terms of DB management but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the translation is surfacing due to a violation of your first principle...

> ...use a unit label that reflects the manner in which you consume or
>   resell the items.

It appears the issue is how they purchase the goods to then resell, am I correct in this assumption or am I missing something?

- The bottle is the container, the pills are the product.
- The box is the container, the candy bar is the product.

Stay away from defining the container as the unit of measurement since that is nothing more than an abstraction. The abstraction can change, the product *most likely* won't. While dog food comes in a bag, the unit of measurement is lbs, since you can have varying bag sizes (abstraction) which contain different amounts.

This may be a simple case of tight coupling throughout the product and your application needs to provide varying levels of abstraction to deal with this. Raw units of measure (lbs, count, etc...) up to abstracted units of measure (bag sizes, bottle sizes, etc...).

Comment: Yes, but you don't sell dog food by the pound, you sell it by the bag. If you sell medication by the pill, I need to know the quantity of pills when you buy a bottle. What I expect is the number of pills you've purchased, not the number of bottles. I will update my question to reflect the difference.

Comment: No, I buy dog food by the lb. You pick up a 40lb bag, a 30lb bag, etc... I don't just purchase a _bag_ of dog food. Same with pills. I need 50, 100, etc... The container doesn't matter to me. It could be a milk carton of pills for all I care. I really think you might be looking at this in a somewhat narrow view due to your applications architecture.

Comment: A 40lb bag and a 30lb bag are two separate items. If that were not the case, a 40lb bad would always be 33% more than a 30lb bag. You also can't ask for 5lbs out of a 30lb bag. The "bag" is the unit you buy, the weight is just a feature.

Comment: @Sparafusile I have to disagree. I respect your approach but that bag size can change on a whim. It's not product, it's packaging. When I look at a screen for my allotment it will be based on weight (distinguishing factor). I'm not implying that abstraction doesn't need to exist (unit size, bundle packaging, etc...), it just sounds like certain architectural decisions within your application are prohibiting you from moving forward in a more fluid manner.

Comment: Perhaps dog food is a bad example, let's try again. If I were a doctor, I would buy a medication by the bottle from the drug manufacturer. The drug may be sold in different sizes (say, "Bottle A", and "Bottle B") so I have to specify which bottle I want. So my order is for 1 "Bottle A" because that's what the manufacturer understand. When I receive it I have to receive it in the quantity that I use it by - cc. So I enter 1000cc for "Bottle A" and my inventory count goes up by 1000. If I received the medication as 1 bottle, it has no meaning because I don't dispense by the bottle.

Comment: This is not a problem with an inflexible program, it's a problem whith users not being able to convert units from what is useful to the OEM when it is purchased to units that are useful to the client when the item is resold. I'll write the application however it works, but I need a way to overcome the hurdle of converting units between purchasing and reselling.

Comment: @Sparafusile If the purchasing unit of measure does not equate to the selling unit of measure, someone has to do the translation. Either the application or a user. If the unit of measure is 1 bottle from the manufacturer, is this auto-populating within your application? Does the user say I purchased 1 bottle manually? Allow the user to set up mappings, templates if you will. Make them easy to edit and maintain. You can leverage the users intimate knowledge of a vendor to do the translation for them. MyTemplate1 (1 btl = 1000 cc) or something similar.

Comment: @AaronMcIver: where to store the templates?  Client, Server?

Comment: @jberger If the unit of measure varies incoming and outgoing, then the first problem is Sparafusile stating to the customer to treat this as the unit which they sell or consume as that is not the case. The goal of the UX should be to minimize the impact of the translation to the customer. Templates as mentioned previously is one way to go about this. The customer may purchase in pallets but unless their business is destined for failure they know how much _product_ exists on that pallet as well.

Comment: @AaronMcIver initially I agree with you. If a vendor sells multiple bottles of medication of different sizes, however, there would be multiple templates for the same inventory item, correct? When the items is purchased from the vendor, the person creating the PO will need to know the different sizes of bottles so they can order the correct one, right? Wouldn't it be easier, then, to just enter the size of the bottle right into the PO instead of determine what size and then selecting the right bottle? Or is this process just a sanity check for the user? Did I miss something in your explanation?

Comment: @jberger That is an architectural decision outside of this scope.

Comment: @Sparafusile I'm not intimate with your application and how data comes in and goes out so this is a bit difficult to answer. The concept of templates needs to remain that, a concept. If this can be handled automatically by the application since it interfaces with these vendors and pulls the data in then by all means do so. Let's say we have Vendor A. If the application is pulling in what Vendor A carries, then at each unique encounter you could ask the user to enter the relationship to product. _We have not seen this unit before. How many cc does 'pallet' equate to with this vendor?_

Comment: @Spara, templates (seems similar to my idea of multipliers) would be so the user wouldn't have to enter the amount every time an order came in.  Let's say user receives 250 different types of packages /week.. well, I'd want to be able to just enter [50] then dropdown to [12 bottles @100mL], instead of entering it manually every time.  That said.. **where/how to store the templates?**  EDIT: just saw your "scope" commment Aaron. Yes, but it'd be helpful to know how others have solved this. ;)

Comment: @Sparafusile Once the user enters the amount, that can be stored and referenced by the application at a later point in time. The key here is uniqueness and making certain that you can guarantee uniqueness between the vendor data (however that is obtained) and your application. This is partly why I believe this is an architectural problem more so than a UX. Once the architectural approach is determined, I think your UX will surface fairly naturally.

Comment: @jberger It's contingent on the application; however I would lean to storing the data outside of the client with a cached copy locally so that is is reachable across multiple devices and platforms.

Comment: @Aaron: this is what I was leaning towards, because of complex relational issues (I have limited DB design XP).  (Only reason for server-side was to keep it available to all client apps without having to import/export.)

Answer (score 0):

There must be convert factor formula working behind scene.
So If there is certain equation like 
1 Pallet = 12 Bag
1 Bag = 10 Item
Then it's easy to display in UOM drop-down,by just identifying item you can 
give these convertible UOM as option to them to semlect the UOM.